# Configuring multiple URIs for Business service in OSB

Tags: osb

I am working in Service Bus (OSB) in jdeveloper 12c. When I configure the business service i want to give 2 end-point URIs. I want to use URI#1 always and I want to use URI#2 only in case of connection failure of URI#1. Please let me know the options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the Oracle docs on *Managing Endpoint URIs for Business Services*. It's very easy to add [multiple endpoints](https://blogs.oracle.com/reynolds/entry/coping_with_failure). I think you'd need load balancing set to `None` in this case, so you only get failover to the second URL when the first one completely stops working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did configure in the same way and it is working !

Comment: Make sure to alter the operational settings so you periodically retry the first URL after it goes offline, otherwise it won't switch back to the primary once it comes back up, and you'll have to do it manually.